# "Digital copy protection between your DVD drive, decoder, and video card" Issue

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, dvd, copy-protection

I just got this error message when trying to play the " Pirates of the Caribbean" DVD on my workstation.

`Windows Media Player cannot play this DVD because there is a problem with digital copy protection between your DVD drive, decoder, and video card. Try installing an updated driver for your video card.`

The video card software is up to date (according to Device Manager)

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked with the manufacturer of your video adapter for a newer driver?  Are you trying to output to your primary monitor, or another display device (like a TV)? Do other copy protected DVDs work as expected?

Comment: Which Edition of Windows 7 do you have? If Home Basic or Starter, what DVD codec are you using?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have Windows 7 Ultimate. How do I find what the DVD codec is?

Comment: @techie007 I have a 3 monitor HDMI setup. One connects to the HDMI output on the mother-board and the other two connect to my Radeon card.  I am playing the video on one of the Radeon card outputs with the other two monitors disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I would just download and install VLC and play the DVD in that.

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html